# Сохранение изменений в css

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, имеется код:

```
$(function(){  
$("#dark").click(function(e){  
    e.preventDefault(); // предотвратить переход  
    $("body").css('background','url(/img/bgdark.png)');  
});  
});
```

Меняет `background`, все хорошо, но при перезагрузке страницы все возвращается обратно.  
Как сохранить изменение в css у пользователя?

**Обновление**

Не работает на сайте. Добавил 2 строки с ссылками:

```
<li><a href="" data-bgcolor="http://site.ru/img/bgdark.png" class="setbg">Темный</a></li>  
<li><a href="" data-bgcolor="http://site.ru/img/bgg.png" class="setbg">Светлый</a></li>
```

И добавил скрипт в head. Нажимаю на ссылку, страница перезагружается, но фон не меняется.

Comment: @Ilya78rus, записывайте значение в cookie или LocalStorage. При последующих загрузках страницы - проверяете: если значение есть, то устанавливаете его, если нет, то значение по дефолту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тестируем тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/zsp5juqv/)

```
function getLS(n) {
    try {
        var ls = localStorage.getItem(n);
        if(typeof ls == 'undefined' || ls === null) return false;
        return $.parseJSON(ls);
    } catch(e){}
}
function setLS(n, v) {
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(n, JSON.stringify(v));
            return true;
    } catch(e){}
}
function setBgColor(){
    $('body').css('background-color', getLS('bgcolor') || '#8080ff');
}
$('.setbg').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    setLS('bgcolor', $(this).data('bgcolor')) && setBgColor();
});
setBgColor();
```

Comment: А если надо с картинками?

Comment: @Ilya78rus, да хоть с бабушкой и дедушкой. Вместо значений текста в атрибуте "data-bgcolor" запишите путь к изображению и измените свойство background-color. [Проверяем][1]. Только очистите localStorage перед тестом.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/zsp5juqv/5/

Comment: @Ilya78rus, код должен быть обёрнут в DOM-Reday

    $(function(){
        // тут весь код
    });

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поковыряться с `LocalStorage`.

В вашем случае вот что будет:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem("bg"))
localStorage.setItem("bg", "/img/bgwhite.png"); //"/img/bgwhite.png"- путь на картинку по умолчанию
$("body").css('background','url('+localStorage.getItem("bg")+')');
$("#dark").click(function(e){  
    localStorage.setItem("bg", "/img/bgdark.png");//"/img/bgdark.png"- путь на картинку на которую изменить
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").css('background','url('+localStorage.getItem("bg")+')');  
});
```

Возможно, чуток с костылями, но по сути должно работать.

Comment: Теперь вообще не работает:

    if (!localStorage.getItem("bg"))  
    localStorage.setItem("bg", "/img/bgg.png");  
    $("body").css('background','url('+localStorage.getItem("bg")+')');  
    $("#dark").click(function(e){    
    localStorage.setItem("bg", "/img/bgdark.png");  
e.preventDefault();  
    $("body").css('background','url('+localStorage.getItem("bg")+')');    
});  
    $("#light").click(function(e){      
localStorage.setItem("bg", "/img/bgg.png"); 
    e.preventDefault();  
    $("body").css('background','url('+localStorage.getItem("bg")+')');  
});